# Stack overflow error in recursive definition

Tags: java, recursion, enums

I have the class definition n JAVA.

```
class ABC 
{ 
    public static final ABC A = new ABC();
    public static final ABC B = new ABC();
}
```

When I call, new ABC(), it runs fine without any error.
But if I remove the word static, it runs into stack overflow error. I am aware that static fields are initiated once. But in this case, the initialization itself is recursive. So ideally even with static property, it should give the same error. Can you someone please explain. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you make this assumption?  If a `static` block is called only _once_, then there is no recursion, right?  Whereas if the constructor is called for an instance, then it would keep getting called indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You answered the question yourself: static fields are initiated once.
That's exactly why the code will not go into an infinite recursion.
You can check this fact yourself attaching a debugger :)